# iOS - Pass Data from Swift to ObjC VC using protocol and delegate

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass data back from Swift VC2 to ObjC VC1 using delegates while dismiss, below is my code.

VC2 (swift)

```swift
//protocol used for sending data back
@objc protocol DataEnteredDelegate: AnyObject {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String)
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil

    // **Go back to VC1**
    @IBAction func doneBtn(_ sender: Any) { 
      session.stop();
      delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(info: "sending date from Swift VC2")
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
}
```

VC1.m (objc)

```objectivec
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"

@interface VC1 () <>
 
@end

@implementation VC1
// **Navigate to VC2**
-(void)goToVC2 {
    VC2 *vc2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2ID"];
    [self presentViewController: vc2 animated: YES completion: nil];
}
@end
```

VC1.h (objc)

```
@interface VC1 : UIViewController

@end
```

How to assign the delegate in VC1 before moving to VC2 and how to implement protocol in VC1 (objc) file i.e. DataEnteredDelegate and the func userDidEnterInformation.

I believe I have completed the swift part of the task but looking for Objc implementation.

Comment: there is no anyobject in objc. protocols work on nsobject when such declaration is not just empty like it is above "<>". so `protocol DataEnteredDelegate: AnyObject` should be `protocol DataEnteredDelegate: NSObject` and as swift is not compiled before objc, headers will fail as long the protocol is not known to objc before that. either declare it upfront or in objc anyway because it is much easier.

Comment: and last but not least when your protoc tells there is some method, then you should implement it on the protocol following class to make it work.

Comment: @OlSen - thank you I will change the AnyObject to NSObject, Can you please add the implementation of the protocol in ObjC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic example...

Assuming we have in Storyboard:

- an Objective-C controller `ObjcViewController` with a "Present It" button
- a Swift controller `SwiftViewController` with a "Done" button, with `Identifier: "SwiftVC"`

and the buttons are connected to the `IBAction` methods...

**ObjcViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ObjcViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**ObjcViewController.m**

```
#import "ObjcViewController.h"

#import "YourProject-Swift.h"

@interface ObjcViewController () <DataEnteredDelegate>

@end

@implementation ObjcViewController

- (IBAction)goToSwiftVC:(id)sender {
    
    SwiftViewController *vc = (SwiftViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SwiftVC"];
    [vc setMyDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}

- (void)userDidEnterInformationWithInfo:(NSString * _Nonnull)info {
    NSLog(@"Delegate sent back: %@", info);
}

@end
```

**SwiftViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

@objc public protocol DataEnteredDelegate {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String)
}

class SwiftViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc public var myDelegate: DataEnteredDelegate?
    
    @IBAction func doneBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        myDelegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: "from SwiftVC")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: worth noting some cases need String to be NSString in the protocol to conform.

Comment: should be:

                          vc.myDelegate = self;

Comment: @men - well, yes... it can be written either way: `[vc setMyDelegate:self];` ***or*** `vc.myDelegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create delegate instance initial with @objc

VC2 (swift)

```
//protocol used for sending data back
@objc protocol DataEnteredDelegate: AnyObject {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String)
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

   @objc weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate?

    // **Go back to VC1**
    @IBAction func doneBtn(_ sender: Any) { 
      session.stop();
      delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(info: "sending date from Swift VC2")
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
}
```

Now in objective-c, VC1.m (objc)

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"

@interface VC1 () <DataEnteredDelegate>
 
@end

@implementation VC1
// **Navigate to VC2**
-(void)goToVC2 {
    VC2 *vc2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2ID"];
    [vc2 delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController: vc2 animated: YES completion: nil];
}

//On dismiss vc2 this delegate will call
- (void)userDidEnterInformationWithInfo:(NSString *)info{
    NSLog(@"%@", info);
}
@end
```